# which prompt command for argument in string array in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Which command line is used for prompt program arguments which attempt the string or any array in vs code, can anyone tell me the code which one should I try?

Comment: rewrite your question, it is not to comprehend

Comment: I couldn't make heads or tails of this request.